# PDAL translation seems to be causing a scaling

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, point-cloud, pdal

I'm trying to georeference a .laz pointcloud in order to correctly show it in QGIS on a map. I notice however that while using the pdal transformation, there is a change in the scale of the point cloud. These are the steps I have taken:

1. I imported the raw point cloud into QGIS in the EPSG:3857 coordinate system and it has the correct dimensions. But now the point cloud is around the zero coordinates since it is not georeferenced
2. I use pdal to do a transformation (only translation) of the point cloud over a large distance (see the pipeline below)

```
    [
    "C:/Documents/PDAL/untransformedFL.laz",
    {
        "type":"filters.transformation",
        "matrix":"1  0  0  415679  0  1  0  6622506  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1"
    },
    {
        "type":"writers.las",
        "scale_x":"0.0001",
        "scale_y":"0.0001",
        "scale_z":"0.0001",
        "offset_x":"auto",
        "offset_y":"auto",
        "offset_z":"auto",
        "filename":"C:/Documents/PDAL/transformedFL.laz"
    }
]
```

3. I import the transformed point cloud into QGIS. When I measure a distance it is completely different (see pictures below)
   **Raw point cloud**
   [image]
   **Translated point cloud**
   [image]

I have used pdal info to grab some points out of both files and the transformation seems to be correctly applied, hence I'm confused at what exactly is happening here.

Comment: EPSG:3857 can't be used like that, the same data translated at different coordinates will give vastly different result. just because the shape/size changes doesn't necessarily means it is wrong you need to place it at the right coordinates and scale it correctly than you can verify if everything look right or not. your point cloud at the origin WILL be wrong

Comment: Thank you for the fast response Louis! Do you have a recommendation on how I would handle this best?

EPSG:3857 is a projected coordinates system and hence flat and 2D. I thought this meant I would be able to just translate all of the coordinates

Comment: Have you verified the metadata on this cloud? Are you sure it's in EPSG:3857? Where did you get it?

Comment: I did not, good point!

Comment: Without having the source coordinates and reference system it is not possible to reproject your coordinates to EPSG:3857 (reproject and not translate). You should provide as much information about the point cloud as you have so we can help you better.